# Label is Undefined

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, google-maps

I'm displayed a postcode into a label on page load in ASP .Net.

The label displays the postcode. I now would like to load google maps with this postcode so have this code

```
    <script>
  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 13,
      center: {lat: 55.0906551, lng: -1.6654200}
    });

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = document.getElementById('<%=LabelPc.ClientID %>').value;
    geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: resultsMap,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else {
        alert('Error: ' + status);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=my_API&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

When the page loads it shows the Error box. When i debug the code in Chrome using F12 the value against

```
var address = document.getElementById('<%=LabelPc.ClientID %>').value;
```

is set as *undefinded*, i have tried using the name from view source but that still gives the same error. I have tried substituting = with # but same issue remains.

Thinking it could be due to the page not loaded i tried `$(document).ready(function ()` but again that didnt work. Not sure where im going wrong?

Edit 1

```
<asp:Label ID="LabelPc" runat="server">

<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: You should set your debugger on the line to get the element. More than likely the element isn't ready yet. Do you have the Google api script in the head or after this label? Try to put it below the label and see if it works then.

Comment: Its at the bottom of the page (not in the head tag)... Let me try moving this to the top

Comment: var address = document.getElementById('<%=LabelPc.ClientID %>').value; ----> that won't work because this element will never get generated '<%=LabelPc.ClientID %>'. Post the entire code of your page.

Comment: I've added the remainder of the code under Edit 1. Whoever posted the answer with .innerHTML and then deleted it had it correct. If theres any reason why innerHTML should not be used please advise?

Comment: @Computer,  you could use innerText or innerHTML. It just depends on what you expect to need.  Using a library like jQuery is generally a better idea because it will give you more cross browser compliance.  In this particular case it wouldn't matter though.  For jquery you would use $("[id$='_LabelPc']").text()   (c# concatenates the ids when you use controls in order to keep the ids unique.)  The easier way is to just use classes or tags to select the right components.